# print window not working First time

Tags: javascript

On button Click I am trying to print #idThermal contents. First time it doesn't show on print preview but Second time onwards it works perfectly fine

```
var divContents = $("#idThermal").html();
var printWindow = window.open('', '', 'height=400,width=800');
printWindow.document.write('<html><head><title></title>');
printWindow.document.write('<link href="/Content/ThermalPrint.css" rel="stylesheet" />');
printWindow.document.write('</head><body  onload=' + printWindow + '.print(); ' + 
printWindow + '.close();>');
printWindow.document.write(divContents);
printWindow.document.write('</body></html>');
printWindow.document.close();
printWindow.print();
```

Comment: On button Click i am trying to print #idThermal contents. First time it doesnt show on print preview but Second tim ownwards it works perfectly fine

Comment: I don't know if you are still struggling with this issue, but I answered a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34025550/5503625

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you mean:

```
var divContents = $("#idThermal").html();
var printWindow = window.open('', '', 'height=400,width=800');
var html = '<html><head><title></title>'+
 '<link href="/Content/ThermalPrint.css" rel="stylesheet" />'+
 '</head><body onload="window.focus(); window.print()">'+
 divContents+
 '</body></html>';
printWindow.document.write(html);
printWindow.document.close();
```