# print window not working 1st time

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to save a PDF using print option, but for some reason the 1st time it doesn't work, it comes up with an empty page. I have [Googled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30775679/print-window-not-working-first-time) and got some solutions, but no luck.

Thanks in advance

```
 $("#btnPrint").click(function () {
     // alert("hi");
     $(".accordion-content").css('display','block');
     var printWindow = window.open('', '', 'height=400,width=1200');
     var strin="";
     printWindow.document.write('<html><head><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/print.css"/></head><body onload="window.focus();" onbeforeunload="window.close();">');
     // alert($(".logoHolder").html());
     printWindow.document.write($(".logoHolder").html());
     $('input[class="subCheck"]:checked').each(function() {
          strin += $("#"+this.value).html()+"<br><br><br>";
     });
     printWindow.document.write(strin);
     // alert();
     printWindow.document.write('</body></html>');
     printWindow.print();
     printWindow.close();
     //$( "#btnPrint" ).trigger( "click" );
});
```

Comment: Your code is all messed up, so I can't tell, but are you trying to print before the DOM has loaded?

Comment: @Nick Yes i am trying DOM

Comment: @MarcB print.doc.write(strin) is inside click handler please re verify, the closing is of each function.

Comment: @3bu1: I see that now. You should clean up the formatting. proper indenting REALLY helps in cases like this.

Comment: document.write is NOT like building a string. When you write out an element, it will close. So adding a closing tag afterwards is not going to do anything. Why open up a new window. Use CSS Print Media and print the current page with the content you want to show.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to check where the problem was, I modified your code so it puts everything in a variable and then write it to the window. It seems like `document.write` doesn't render the contents before you try to print the window. Instead, I changed the `innerHTML` of the `body`, which seems to be working fine:

```
$("#btnPrint").click(function(){
  $(".accordion-content").css('display','block');
  var printWindow = window.open('', '', 'height=400,width=1200');
  var html = ''+
    '<html>'+
    '<head>'+
    '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/print.css"/>'+
    '</head>'+
    '<body onload="window.focus();" onbeforeunload="window.close();">'+
    $(".logoHolder").html();
  $('input[class="subCheck"]:checked').each(function() {
    html += $("#"+this.value).html()+"<br><br><br>";
  });
  html += '</body></html>';
  //printWindow.document.write(html);
  printWindow.document.body.innerHTML = html;
  printWindow.print();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hoqp8zxp/

**Update to help you with your css**

Regarding the CSS, I believe there are a couple of problems:

1. The new window location is `about:blank` (or something similar) so relative paths won't work. You should use an absolute path (`http://host/css/print.css` instead of `css/print.css`)
2. Since stylesheets load asynchronously, you might have to use a hack in order to execute the print command once the stylesheet is fully loaded. Something like this: https://viget.com/inspire/js-201-run-a-function-when-a-stylesheet-finishes-loading *Note: You could also just load the styles using a style tag*

This is the updated code using the hack mentioned above (using an stylesheet from StackOverflow):

```
$("#btnPrint").click(function(){
  $(".accordion-content").css('display','block');
  var printWindow = window.open('', '', 'height=400,width=1200');
  var cssFile = 'http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/all.css?v=544053bd81fe';//Replace with your absolute path
  var html = ''+
    '<html>'+
    '<head>'+
    '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="'+cssFile+'"/>'+
    '</head>'+
    '<body onload="window.focus();" onbeforeunload="window.close();">'+
    $(".logoHolder").html();
  $('input[class="subCheck"]:checked').each(function() {
    html += $("#"+this.value).html()+"<br><br><br>";
  });
  html += '</body></html>';
  //printWindow.document.write(html);
  printWindow.document.body.innerHTML = html;
  var img = document.createElement('img');
  printWindow.document.body.appendChild(img);
  img.style.display = 'none';
  img.onerror = function(){
    printWindow.print();
  };
  img.src = cssFile;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hoqp8zxp/1/

Comment: @3bu1 I just updated my answer, see if it works for you

Answer (score 1):

I use setTimeOut for this problem and work fine for me.I modified your code with my solution.

```
$("#btnPrint").click(function () {
 // alert("hi");
 $(".accordion-content").css('display','block');
 var printWindow = window.open('', '', 'height=400,width=1200');
 var strin="";
 printWindow.document.write('<html><head><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/print.css"/></head><body onload="window.focus();" onbeforeunload="window.close();">');
 // alert($(".logoHolder").html());
 printWindow.document.write($(".logoHolder").html());
 $('input[class="subCheck"]:checked').each(function() {
      strin += $("#"+this.value).html()+"<br><br><br>";
 });
 printWindow.document.write(strin);
 // alert();
 printWindow.document.write('</body></html>');
 printWindow.close();
setTimeout(function () {
            printWindow.focus();
            printWindow.print();
             }, 1000);
});
```